# How can I use onClick on stateless component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use onClick on a stateless compoenent but it's reject an error like : `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

I need to show and hide component on click.
Example when I click on the `<ResultCard/>` component I want to hide him and show `<ResultDetail/>`

**State React Component :**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ResultCard from "./ResultCard";
import "../../assets/css/Result.css";
import Spinner from "../Spinner";
import { getApiToken, getParisByPrice } from "../../services/api";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import "../../assets/css/BudgetEntry.css";
import modify from "../../assets/images/modify.png";
import ResultDetail from "./ResultDetail";

class Results extends Component {
  state = { 
    priceValue: "",
    showResult: true
  };

  showResultDetail = () => {

    this.setState({ showResult: false });
  };

  closeResultDetails = () => {

    this.setState({ showResult: true });
  };



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="results-container">


        {this.state.loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <div className={"row"}>
            {this.state.showResult ? 
            (
              this.state.paris.map(details => (
                <ResultCard
                  key={details.id}
                  id={details.id}
                  showResultDetail={this.showResultDetail}
                  prefix={details.prefix}
                  costPerDay={details.average_cost_per_day}
                  logoSports={details.infrastructure.map(home =>
                    home.logo_path.map(path_image => (
                      <img
                        src={path_image}
                        alt="icon-sports"
                        style={{ width: 20 }}
                        key={path_image}
                      />
                    ))
                  )}
                />
              ))
            ) 
              : 
            (
              <ResultDetail closeResultDetail={this.closeResultDetails}/>
            )
            }
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Results;
```

**ResultCard (who is stateless component):**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../assets/css/ResultCard.css';

const ResultCard = ({prefix, costPerDay, logoSports, showResultDetail, id}) => {

  return (
    <div className="card" onClick={showResultDetail} id={id}>
      <p style={{margin:5}}>{prefix}</p>
      <p style={{margin:1}}>arrondissement</p>
      <p>{costPerDay} $</p>
      {logoSports}
    </div>
  )


};

export default ResultCard;
```

**ResultDetail (who is stateless component):**

```
import React from 'react';

const ResultDetail = (closeResultDetail) => (

      <div onClick={closeResultDetail}>
        <p>Result detail</p>
      </div>
) 


export default ResultDetail;
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here

```js
const ResultDetail = (closeResultDetail) => (
```

You need to destructure it from the `props` object like this:

```js
const ResultDetail = ({closeResultDetail}) => (
```

Or use it from props directly like this:

```js
const ResultDetail = (props) => (
 <div onClick={props.closeResultDetail}>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain me why please ?

Comment: Functional components always receive one parameter: `props`. When you use this syntax `= ({myProp}) =>` you are [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `props` object into individual variables. So when you leave out the `{}`, you're really just renaming `props` to `closeResultDetail` instead of referencing the specific prop you want.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

in `Results` you define

```
showResultDetail = () => {
    this.setState( {showResult: false });
};
```

as a function without arguments. You then pass

```
showResultDetail={(e) => this.showResultDetail(e)}
```

as a function with an event argument to your `ResultCard`. If you change that to

```
showResultDetail={this.showResultDetail}
```

your problem might already be fixed.

**Edit:** Here is a minimal snippet that does what you're looking for, I think.

```js
const ResultCard = ({showResultDetail, show}) => {
  return <div className="card" onClick={showResultDetail}>{show?'Click me!':''}</div>
};
class Results extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    priceValue: "",
    showResult: true
  };
  showResultDetail = () => {
    this.setState({ showResult: false });
  };
  render() {
      return <ResultCard show={this.state.showResult}
           showResultDetail={this.showResultDetail}/>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Results/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your state component

```
  showResultDetail = () => {

    this.setState({ showResult: false });
  };

   render() {

        ....
        <ResultCard 
        ....
        show={this.state.showResult}
         //defer the execution of the method
        onClick={(e) => this.showResultDetail(e)}/> 


    }
```

resultCard.js

```
const ResultCard = ({prefix, costPerDay, logoSports, showResultDetail, id, show}) => {

  if(show) 
     return (
    <div className="card" onClick={showResultDetail} id={id}>
      <p style={{margin:5}}>{prefix}</p>
      <p style={{margin:1}}>arrondissement</p>
      <p>{costPerDay} $</p>
      {logoSports}
    </div>
  );


};
```

Comment: whats your current behavior